# How to turn off buffering of stdout in C

Tags: c, stdout

I want to turn off the buffering for the stdout for getting the exact result for the following code

```
while(1) {
    printf(".");
    sleep(1);
}
```

The code printf bunch of '.' only when buffer gets filled.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string? (in C)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)

Comment: Candidate for *questions that get asked the most on StackOverflow*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)

Answer (score -14, accepted):

Use `fflush(stdout)`. You can use it after every `printf` call to force the buffer to flush.

Comment: This does not really "turn off buffering of stdout in C".

Answer (score 128):

You can use the [setvbuf function](http://web.archive.org/web/20171126034853/http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/setvbuf.html):

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

---

Here're some other links to the function.

- [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/setvbuf.html)
- [C/C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setvbuf)

Comment: Good one. Thx. By the way `setbuf(stream, NULL);` is equivalent to `setvbuf(stream, NULL, _IONBF, BUFSIZ);`

Comment: One caveat: It's only legal to call `setbuf` or `setvbuf` as the **very first** operation on a stream before any input or output is performed on it. Thus using `fflush` explicitly is usually a better idea.

Answer (score 26):

You can also use setbuf

```
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
```

This will take care of everything

Comment: this is not a very good answer, quoting Newlib: `Both ANSI C and the System V Interface Definition (Issue 2) require
<<setbuf>>.  However, they differ on the meaning of a <<NULL>> buffer
pointer: the SVID issue 2 specification says that a <<NULL>> buffer
pointer requests unbuffered output.  For maximum portability, avoid
<<NULL>> buffer pointers.`

Comment: @MightyPork Newlib is just flat-out **wrong**.  [The POSIX 2 specification for `setbuf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/setbuf.html) states: "`setvbuf(stream, buf, _IONBF, BUFSIZ)` if buf is a null pointer." [`_IONBF` means unbuffered](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.6p2)  Both [POSIX 7](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setbuf.html) and [the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.5) all agree, and have agreed for [decades](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#4.9.5.5).

Answer (score -3):

Use `fflush(FILE *stream)` with `stdout` as the parameter.

http://www.elook.org/programming/c/fflush.html

Comment: This does not turn off buffering, it flushes the buffer once.

Answer (score -4):

You can do this:

```
write(1, ".", 1);
```

instead of this:

```
printf(".");
```

Comment: use `STDOUT_FILENO`