# Flag for gcc to turn off buffering of stdout?

Tags: gcc

Is there any flag for `gcc` or `g++` that turns the buffering off for `stdout`?
Like `python -u` turns off buffering of `stdout` ,`stdin` and `stderr` in python.

Comment: Not a gcc flag, but see [How to turn off buffering of stdout in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876660/how-to-turn-off-buffering-of-stdout-in-c).

Comment: I want to turn off buffering through gcc not through c.

Comment: @c4rbon, that's not the compiler's job. That's your code's job.

Comment: @Mat,i thought if it is available in python, it might be available in gcc.

Comment: @c4rbon: your comparing apples and oranges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC, as a compiler, only generates an executable. It has no real knowledge of buffering or even of streams. Only the C runtime knows what your `stdout` and `stderr` are. You need to tell the C runtime, at obviously runtime, to disable buffering.

By comparison, the Python runtime is an interpreter. As an interpreter, it is the one to set up your streams and can disable the buffering if you ask it to.