# Python subprocess cannot capture output of Windows program

Tags: python, windows, winapi, cmd, subprocess

Using `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` stops the output from going to the console, but nothing is captured.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> proc = subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Users\\me\\program.exe'])
>>> ERROR: please provide an argument
// TRUNCATED USAGE OUTPUT
proc.wait()
0
>>> proc = subprocess.Popen([''C:\\Users\\me\\program.exe''], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> proc.communicate()
('', None)
```

I've tried every combination available on stackoverflow. `shell=True` hasn't worked. Spawning a sub `cmd` hasn't worked. `subprocess.check_output` captures nothing. I'm happy to retry any of these commands in the comments.

I am guessing this has something to do with out the program is attaching to a shell.

This is the assembly the program uses to output (`mcall` is just a macro to align memory to 16 bits). The reason I include this is in case `GetStdHandle` is affecting things.

```
console_write PROC
; rcx   MSG
; rdx   LEN
  prologue
  push    rcx
  push    rdx
  xor     rcx, rcx
  mov     ecx, [stdout]
  mcall   GetStdHandle
  mov     rcx, rax
  xor     rdx, rdx
  pop     r8    ; len
  pop     rdx   ; msg
  push    0
  mov     r9, rsp
  push    0
  mcall   WriteConsoleA
  pop     rcx
  pop     rcx
  epilogue
console_write ENDP
```

I'm stumped on this one. I've done this so many times on Linux. I just don't know enough about Windows internals to sort this out. Thanks!

---

**Edit: Additional things I have tried:**

Admin (also with STDERR capture)

```
C:\Windows\system32>C:\Python27\python.exe
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:19:30) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> proc = subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Users\\me\\program.exe'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> proc.communicate()
('', '')
```

STDOUT File Redirect

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('C:\\Users\\me\\program.exe > out.txt')
0
>>> f = open('out.txt', 'r')
>>> f.read()
''
```

STDERR File Redirect

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('C:\\Users\\me\\program.exe 2>out.txt')
ERROR: please provide an argument
// TRUNCATED USAGE OUTPUT
0
>>> open('out.txt', 'r').read()
''
```

Command Line Capture Fails (suppresses output from going to cmd, but nothing is captured)

```
program.exe > out.txt
```

Comment: did you try stderr?

Comment: Yes. Same issue. `>>> proc.communicate()
('', '')` (full command in another comment)

Comment: or maybe you should run it as admin, did you check that?

Comment: Same with admin.

Comment: you can see its output on cmd right? so, write that in a .bat file, then launch that bat file with your python script and and see what happens ...

Comment: Hmmm, cannot capture from a batch file or on the command line either.

Comment: are you sure your exe file is not corrupted? and did you try win32.client module? you can run applications,shell commands and vbs with win32.client too...

Comment: EXE is fine. Assembled with ML64 (I've rebuilt it today with no change). It outputs to console and returns 0. Capturing stdout suppresses the output but fails to capture.

Comment: see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33059905/how-to-open-a-cmd-shell-in-windows-and-issue-commands-to-that-shell-using-python ( the last answer ),,,,,,, or see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304097/retrieving-the-command-output-of-a-hidden-console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A coworker pointed out the issue. It turns out that `WriteConsole` cannot be redirected to a file, it can only be used with console handles. [[1]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/high-level-console-input-and-output-functions) [[2]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-handles)

This [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42993785/1176872) gives an outline for how to solve it. I've implemented it in Python if anyone else has this problem.

```
import win32console
import subprocess
import msvcrt
import os

ccsb = win32console.CreateConsoleScreenBuffer()
fd = msvcrt.open_osfhandle(ccsb, os.O_APPEND)
proc = subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Users\\me\\program.exe'], stdout=fd)
proc.wait()
ccsb.ReadConsoleOutputCharacter(100, win32console.PyCOORDType(0,0)) # reads 100 characters from the first line
```

The better solution for me was to change `WriteConsoleA` to `WriteFile`, using the same `StdHandle`.

```
console_write PROC
; rcx   MSG
; rdx   LEN
  prologue
  push    rcx
  push    rdx
  xor     rcx, rcx
  mov     ecx, [stdout]
  mcall   GetStdHandle
  mov     rcx, rax
  ; Write File
  pop     r8    ; len
  pop     rdx   ; msg
  ; unalign for odd number of pushed args
  mov     rbx, rsp
  sub     rbx, 8        
  and     rbx, 0Fh
  sub     rsp, rbx
  ; args
  mov     rcx, rax        ; handle
  xor     r9, r9
  push    0               ; 1 arg (ununaligns)
  sub     rsp, 20h        ; shadow 
  call    WriteFile
  add     rsp, 28h        ; shadow + arg
  add     rsp, rbx        ; realign
  epilogue
console_write ENDP
```

Comment: very unusual for x64 asm code. i mean how you work with stack. all this push/pop in the middle. need not forget about stack align before every call. why not use usual technique  with `mov` params (4,5..) to stack ?

Comment: @RbMm Any example of the usual code? I have a macro for align and call for 0-4 arguments. This was the one call I was doing with 5. I will eventually write a new macro where you provide the number of arguments and it does the align / unalign based on whether it is even or odd. Most the code I saw relied on tracking if the stack was aligned or not. This doesn't care if it is aligned or unaligned. If there is a better way though, I'm always open to learn.

Comment: look for any windows x64 binary. really you only complicate your own life by this. special macros absolute not need. you need **once** in function prolog align stack. and then never use push or pop for args. simply use *mov*. say `mov [rsp+20h],arg5`, `mov [rsp+28h],arg6` and so on. and code became smaller and more redable.

Comment: @RbMm The `sub rsp, 0xNN` requires knowledge of whether the stack is aligned or unaligned. `0xNN` would need to be `shadow_space + 8 * n_stack args + alignment`. My code just tests for alignment and subtracts it first. I could do the same thing and just use the result of `and rbx, 0Fh` as the `alignment` in the above equation, but it makes no difference. I'm not a compiler and don't want to track whether things are aligned or unaligned, so the test is useful. Then if I change the code above a call it doesn't mess up the alignment for the call.

Comment: on windows (how minimum) we always have this knowledge - at any function first instruction `stack == 16*n+8`

Comment: so all is really much more simply - we know stack akigment at function begin. and we need do decrement rsp on `8+k*16` in prolog. how minimum on `0x28`

Comment: If you're in control of the source, then certainly change to `WriteFile`. Using `WriteConsoleA` offers no advantages and comes with the downside that it only accepts console screen-buffer handles. `WriteConsoleW` would be a different story. It's the only reliable way to write the full range of Unicode to the console as UTF-16 text in Windows 7, since the older console's support for codepage 65001 (UTF-8) is buggy for output.  (Even in Windows 10 the console is still buggy for reading input as UTF-8.)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to catch stderr as well?

```
proc = subprocess.Popen([''C:\\Users\\me\\program.exe''], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

**UPDATE**

You can try to read output line by line while the process is running, for example:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(exe, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
while True:
    retcode = p.poll()
    print p.stdout.readline()
    if retcode is not None:
        break
```

Comment: Yep. Same deal. `>>> proc = subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Users\\me\\program.exe'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> proc.communicate()
('', '')`

Comment: `os.system()` does not capture output. Redirecting to a file like `os.system(program.exe > out.txt)` causes no output to be written to the file.

Comment: And `os.system(program.exe 2> out.txt)`?

Comment: It's printing to `stdout`. When I do that the output goes to the console and nothing is captured in the file. Will edit it in above.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I have enough rep to suggest a question is a possible duplicate, nor comment, so I'm posting this as an answer because although douggard's answer led me down the right track thinking-wise, it didn't actually work in my case and I had a hard time getting a working solution.

There's an answer here that captures CONOUT and worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38749458/1675668