# Pass binary data to stdin of a program based on its stdout

Tags: c, windows, security, stdout, stdin

I have a program A, which prints some text data, then does a gets() reading from stdin.
I want to create a program/script which will read the stdout of A (text data) and based on the output pass data (binary) to its stdin.

The program is a simple exploitation demo (format string vulnerability to dump stack, then based on dumped values craft exploit payload which is then passed via gets to trigger a buffer overflow and execute the crafted shellcode).

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char buffer[20];
    BOOL(__stdcall *getName)(LPSTR lpBuffer, LPDWORD nSize) = GetComputerNameA;

    printf("The argument is: ");
    printf(argv[1]);
    printf("\r\n");

    printf("Enter a message: ");
    gets(buffer);
    printf("Your message is: %s", buffer);

    TCHAR name[20];
    DWORD len = 19;
    getName(name, &len);
    printf("Your computer is called %s", name);
    printf("\r\n");
}
```

I have tried doing this in python via target.stdout.readline() and target.stdin.write(), but the readline hangs and never returns.
I also tried in C# via the OutputDataReceived event, but I was only able to read the output if I wasn't passing any input. Once I redirected stdin, I wasn't able to read anything. Hangs also occured.

My question is how do I achieve this?

EDIT:
Sample of the python code executing the program

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
x = Popen(['test.exe', '"%08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x"', 'start'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

out = x.stdout.readline()
print(out)
input("{press enter}")

data = bytearray(...payload...)
payload = buffer(data)
x.stdin.write(payload)
input("{press enter}")
```

Comment: `char buffer[20];` looks small for `gets()`.  Best to move to a bigger buffer and `fgets()`.

Comment: The buffer size is intentionally this small. It is meant to overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C `printf` uses buffered output. When stdout is to a terminal then the buffer is flushed after each `"\n"`, but in this case the output is to a pipe, so it is buffered to several k-bytes worth of data. The buffer is never flushed, and is not written to the pipeline.

To avoid python waiting for the buffered data forever, you can add `fflush(stdout)` after each `printf` or [disable buffering altogether](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7876756/4955498).