# In Eclipse, Is there one-time solution about buffer problem?(using scanf after printf then It's impossible to print something)

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, mingw

I'm using eclipse in Windows, and minGW.
I write the easy code like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c;
    printf("input: ");
    scanf("%c",&c);

    return 0;
}
```

Buffer error is rised, and I search the stackoverflow. It told me to use fflush().
And it works.
But, I must write fflush() after each printf().
I don't wanna do this.
I want to solve this problem in one statement.

Comment: You could change `scanf("%c", &c);` to `scanf(" %c%*c", &c);`.

Comment: Also don't use `fflush()` with `stdin`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin. If you want to clean everything that is left in `stdin` you can declare `int ch;` and  use `while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);` to clean it instead. And it should be put after the `scanf()`, not after `printf()`.

Comment: The shown code should not throw a buffer error. Are you sure you posted your real [example]? -- Anyway, Eclipse as most other IDEs does not provide a real terminal. And all output is commonly buffered some way, depending on the kind of output target. Eclipse seems to use a pipe, which might be handled as a file that is probably block buffered. If you use a real terminal, this is commonly line buffered, which means that output needs a `'\n'` before it is shown. I'm afraid you need that `fflush(stdout)` or set the buffer mode.

Comment: Try [setvbuf()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7876756/1983398).