# POSIX C/C++ sleep() and usleep() not working? (Raspberry PI)

Tags: c++, c, raspberry-pi, posix

I wrote a small programm on my RasPI and have trouble with the `sleep()` and `usleep()` functions. both of them don't work. When I use `usleep()` with a number below 1000000 (below 1 second) it works, whenever i try to use a number that should let the program sleep for 1 second or more, it doesn't work. I've been working on making the Digital pin HIGH for a given time.

I've tried to shrink the program to `printf()` and to sleep only:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{

    while (true)
    {
        sleep(1);
        printf("%.2f", 10.1);
    }
}
```

Comment: How complete is the standard library you are using? Can you `#include` `<chrono>` and `<thread>`?

Comment: Please be more specific than "it doesn't work". Does it not sleep, sleep forever, sleep strangely, crash, ...?

Comment: so, by executing the code it should print 10.1 in the console, right?
well it does it's job when using usleep() up to 999999 but when i try usleep 1000000 or sleep(1) it doesn't loop the print, in fact it prints nothing in the console, just stuck in an infinite loop

Comment: same issue after including 
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

Comment: If you remove the looping, does the issue persist?

Comment: no, once i remove the loop it does work, same if i loop it and use usleep(500000) which prints it every 0.5s

Comment: And if you replace `sleep(1)` with `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));` ?

Comment: And does the problem persist if you flush the output buffer, e.g. by `printf("%.2f\n", 10.1);`

Comment: okay, works after flush, thanks

Comment: Use this example to learn some basics of how to use GDB. I was able to quickly determine that it wasn't sleeping forever using this on my PI.

Comment: FYI `usleep` is deprecate instead use `nanosleep`

Answer (score 1):

works after flushing the output buffer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>


int main()
{

    while (true)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        printf("%.2f\n", 10.1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also explicitly flush it if you don't want the newline: `printf("%.2f", 10.1);` `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: Luks, Appending a `'\n'` dose not certainly flush `stdout`, yet commonly does.  `fflush(stdout);` is certain.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica appending `'\n'` forces the flush because stdout is usually line buffered by default. Buffering can be disabled at all with `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0)` (as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7876756/11336762) answer)

Comment: @RobertoCaboni There is no default buffering, such as _line buffering_, setting for `stdout` specified by C.  Instead your assertions seem to be based on common, though not required, behavior.  There is instead much  [implementation defined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39536212/2410359)  functionality.  Refer to C17dr § 7.21.3 3.  Yet perhaps I have read the spec incorrectly and there is something in the spec to support your claim?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica no claims about `_IOLBF` default required by specification, on my side. :) It was just an assumption, probably rushed though based experience on windows/linux command shells, about it being an unofficial habit used in common environments. It was probably a rushed assertion, as (for example) I found this rule for GNU libc (see [this article](https://eklitzke.org/stdout-buffering)): stdin -> line-buffered; stdout (TTY) -> line-buffered; stdout (not a TTY) -> fully-buffered; stderr -> unbuffered.

Comment: So, of course no default buffering is required by the standard. My point is just that every implementation must have an "init value" (init != default) and that a common implementation choice is to initialize stdouts in line buffered mode (including, apparently, the RasPI console used by the OP). Thanks to this discussion I discovered the difference between TTY/notTTY that I wasn't aware about.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni Fair point about "line buffered mode (including, apparently, the RasPI console used by the OP".  Yet to emphasize, `fflush(stdout);` is certain.  That becomes more important as one targets highly portable code.